# how to autocomplete method name

Tags: java, eclipse, hotkeys

Is there hotkey which can let me auto complete method name in Eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> does most autocompletions for you in Eclipse.

Comment: can I change this key. Ctrl + Space is taken by another program.

Comment: @user496949 Yes you can change the key

Comment: @user496949 - try Window > Preferences > General > Keys

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger Auto Assist in Eclipse.

### To change the Auto Assist Hot key in Eclipse

follow these from the menubar
Window > Preferences > General > Keys > *Type* `Content Assist` *in the Filter TextField*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you type `.` autocomplete appears automatically. You can also trigger it via <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>.